# Displaying returned array as radio buttons

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to display a set of radio buttons (male or female) on my index page. Within my Form I build the form like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add('gender', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'choices'  => array(
            'Male' => 1,
            'Female' => 2,
        )));
}
```

Then within the Controller:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $participantEntry = new Participants();

    $form = $this->createForm(ParticipantsType::class, $participantEntry,[
        'action' => $request->getUri()
    ]);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    return $this->render('SurveyBundle:Page:index.html.twig',
        ['form' => $form->createView()]);

}
```

However, I'm not sure how to actually display as RadioButtons within my Twig file, this is what I've tried:

```
{% for g in form.gender %}
    {{ g.value }}
{%  endfor %}
```

BTW: The $gender within my Entity is an int

Which doesn't work, does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the `add` into builder as follow

```
->add('gender', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices'  => array(
        'Male'   => 1,
        'Female' => 2,
    ),
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => false 
);
```

The combination of `'expanded' => true` and `'multiple' => false` will generate radio buttons, then in twig, just use

```
form_widget(form.gender)
```

Comment: Perfect! Is their, any way of actually customising the returned radio buttons?

Comment: Sorry let me be more specific. Is there a way to iterate through each gender within the array? So i can wrap a div around each item?

Comment: @KTOV yes, of course, you can iterate as you were done and write ALL THE HMTL structure (not only external div but all the structure) and use the value of the radio

Comment: It doesn't work with the way i have done it. It states that value cannot be converted to string?

Comment: No I haven't, but I have just marked it. Could you please tell me how to iterate through? I've iterated through, however the labels are not being displayed

Comment: @KTOV: read this http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html maybe can help you understand better how this works :)

Comment: @KTOV if you want to display also labels, you need to use `form_label` aswell